# Is there an increase in sales of child-size coffins?

Tags: united-states, mortality, vaccines, canada

A number of ["news sites" have been reporting an increase in child-sized coffins](https://www.westernstandard.news/news/casket-manufacturer-reports-unprecedented-orders-of-child-size-coffins/article_5b7a2c18-014b-11ed-8f21-2bbdbcefeaa6.html).  (The linked is an example, there are many more). The implication being there is an increase of childrens deaths, ascribed to the COVID vaccine? From the *Western Standard* linked:

> A Toronto-based casket manufacturer has taken to Twitter to report historically high child casket sales by the company he works for. The casket salesman, who asked to be referred to by his first name only, told the Western Standard his company has never seen such a significant rise in bulk sales of caskets typically used to bury children. Mick said all producers are seeing this huge uptick in youth-sized coffin sales.
>
> Children's caskets typically accommodate the bodies of children aged between 18 months to around 10 years of age.
>
> "There's no denying it, I would say the sales versus the pre-pandemic period were probably up 30%, maybe 40%. And in this industry, for a 30% or 40% increase in sales, something dramatic has to have happened. And it's not just local to specific towns," Mick said. "It's throughout North America, at least the customers we deal with. We have a few customers over in England, through Ireland, and Scotland as well. And they're also seeing some growth, but not as radical as [it is] in North America. North America seems to be experiencing it at a higher rate than everywhere else that that we deal with specifically."
>
> . . . Vaccines are killing children . . .
>
> Mick said he and his family have an idea about what is responsible for the unprecedented increase in coffin sales. "We all think it's something to do with the vaccines. I don't want to say we're a group of people who weren't convinced [by the science], but you know, I think [a family member] got one dose, had a horrible reaction and then nobody else in his family got it. No one in my family has gotten it. It's something serious, causing young people to just immediately die."

Are these claims true?
Have there been 1) an increase in coffin sales 2) an increase of child death 3) due to the vaccine?

Comment: This contains 3 questions. You need to split it into three separate posts.

Comment: @RedSonja That would just be wasteful, the main claim seems pretty clear.

Comment: @pipe, no, OP sneaked some anti-vax propaganda into what could have been a useful question.

Comment: @RedSonja What do you mean by that? OP has written very little apart from the quoted article, and everything written is directly supported by the quote, so unless the quote is fabricated I can't see what would be "propaganda".

Comment: Could we get a 2nd source, ideally closer to origin (so 'accuracy of report' from Western Standard gets less focus; the src present perhaps to be kept for notability)? The chosen src seems a bit dubious in itself, eg claiming ("only first name") as other srcs do include a full name, like this interview with 'the manufacturer:' https://rairfoundation.com/coffins-for-children-ordered-in-bulk-first-time-in-over-30-years-exclusive-interview/

Comment: I've tagged this with Canada and US because the quote ultimately claims the increase there (in "North America") was higher than in some other countries they (also) claim to sell to.

Answer (score 9):

I cannot find any data on the sales of coffins, but we can look at [excess mortality by age group](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/excess-mortality-p-scores-average-baseline-by-age?country=GBR%7EDEU%7EUSA).

[image]

We can decidedly see that there is no rising trend in the excess mortality in the age 0-14 group. In fact, the numbers show that the US (where presumably this claim originates) in this age group the current mortality is 40% below the average from the period 2015-2019. This could be partially due to delayed reporting effects, (Mortality number for recent months may not always be complete.) but there is certainly no evidence for increase mortality under children *from any cause*.

Whether there is an increased demand for child sized coffins I cannot say (maybe there is a fad for gothic children's room design that I am unaware of), but it is certainly not due to increased child deaths. (Unless this trend change is super recent.)

Update:
As far as date data from Canada goes here is the excess mortality rate for Canada based on data from the [Human Mortality Database](https://mpidr.shinyapps.io/stmortality/)[image]
[image]
[image]
This shows that in the first 9 weeks of 2022 Canada did show excess mortality in the 0-14 age. However, this seems perfectly inline with the excess mortality in Canada in preceding pandemic years (before the release of any vaccines.)

Comment: "maybe there is a fad for gothic children's room design" I am speculating, but I think simple fashion changes in the popularity of burial versus cremation (which tend to use much simpler caskets) could easily account for a far bigger shift in casket-makers orders than non-funeral related uses and vaccine deaths put together. The [graph in this article](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Burial_vs_Cremation) shows a huge shift *away* from burials up to 2019, but suggests to me fashions can change quickly.

Comment: Or people might start putting 8-9 year olds into child coffins instead of adult ones. Or someone might have started building coffins for 11-12 year olds. Or dead foetuses might get more burials now.

Comment: Note that the mortality graphs are all relative to previous years and child mortality is very low in absolute numbers. Total mortality in the US is around 4 million per year, mortality in the 0 to 14 range is under 10000 a year and more than half of that is below one year old. In other words, if any non trivial proportion of coffins are child size these are certainly not used to bury children, there just aren't that many child deaths.